# Get variable addresses in linker map file

Tags: gcc, ld

In a program for a micro-controller some regions must be in a special memory section. These has been declared in the C source file as

```
static int Foo __attribute__((section(".ocm")));
```

In the linker script this section is placed at the appropriate address:

```
MEMORY {
  ram_0 : ORIGIN = 0, LENGTH = 0x100000
  ram_1 : ORIGIN = 0xFFFF0000, LENGTH = 0xFE00
}

SECTION {
.text : {
  //     here are the normal sections
  } > ram_0

.ocm (NOLOAD) : {
    __ocm_start = .;
    *(.ocm)
    __osm_end = .;
  } > ram_1
}
```

With that configuration all symbols are included in the map file. But the variable `Foo` is missing. The NOLOAD attribute can be applied since there are no initialized variables in that section. It was necessary because a the ELF output is post-processed and that section must be excluded from that process.

How can I convince the linker to included the symbols in the special section in the map file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GNU linker unfortunately lists only public symbols. If the variable is declared as `static` since it's private for the file scope, it will not be listed in the map file. It's necessary to change the code to get its address in the map file:

```
int Foo __attribute__((section(".ocm")));
```